# How to integrate Firebase with Glide ('using' method)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm trying to use Firebase integration with Glide and for some reason, 
`Glide.using()` cannot resolve this method.
I did add:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
```

Into `build.gradle` and also:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
```

Here is the part which I'm trying to use Glide:

```
   mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mStorageRef.child("images/Puffer-fish-are-pretty-damn-cute.jpg");

// Load the image using Glide
        Glide.with(this)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader()) // cannot resolve method using!
                .load(mStorageRef)
                .into(imageView);
```

I hope you can help me with that, didn't find any solutions online.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this, please change this line:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Comment: See [this issue on Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/731) to track support for Glide 4.0.

Comment: Here the documentation to switch to Glide 4.X https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage Official documentation is still outdated

Answer (score 2):

Glide v4 is using module loaders with the annotation processor library.

Create `AppGlideModule` and then register `FirebaseImageLoader`. When loading images use `StorageReference`.

Here it is in details.

**Add libraries in gradle**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
```

**Extend the module and register**

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class, new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

**Load images with ref**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(photoUrl);
StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(uri.getPath());
Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
    .load(ref)
    .into(thumb);
```

Comment: The image does not updates once it is changed from the same storage referance.